# integrating multifunctionality in single app

Tags: iphone, ios4

I do have an Idea to integrate with my application. I want to create multiple application within a single one application.

Like and application containing Weather application as well as image processing application + camera based application.

I want to know Is this thing possible with iphone application?

Please suggest me is this possible with iPhone app development and is it allowed by apple or not.

thanks for your suggestion in advance.